# Usefulness of a claim that Yoneda embedding reflects exactness

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

By "Yoneda embedding reflects exactness" I mean:

> If we have a sequence
>   $$ A \overset{\alpha}{\to} B \overset{\beta}{\to} C $$
>   such that for every object $M$
>   $$\hom(M,A) \overset{\alpha*}{\to} \hom(M,B) \overset{\beta*}{\to} \hom(M,C) $$
>   is exact, then the original sequence is exact. 
>   (I'm assuming we are working in an abelian category, of course.)

I agree that this theorem is interesting, but I find it hard to believe that someone would use this to show exactness of a concrete sequence (and that this theorem would be an optimal way to go in that circumstance). I would like if someone could prove me wrong by an example.

Or maybe my thinking is too "close to the ground" and usefulness of this claim lies elsewhere. I would be grateful for an example all the same.

Comment: An example of usefulness of this property : you can use it to prove, without much trouble, exactness properties of left and right adjoints

Comment: I think this statement is intended to be reassuring more than useful. It tells you that exactness in an abelian category reduces ultimately to exactness for abelian groups. And maybe hints at Freyd-Mitchell.

Answer (score 0):

This is too close to the standard definition of exactness to admit interesting examples, I think. It says that $A\to B\to C$ is exact if and only if: a map from $M$ into $B$ factors through $A$ if and only if its extension to $C$ vanishes. But this is just what exactness means, while living in an abelian category means that one has some distinguished choices for $M$, namely the kernel of $\beta$ and the image of $\alpha$. Yet how do we verify that a map $K\to B\to C$ in an abelian category is a kernel, for instance? We verify that $0\to\mathrm{hom}(M,K)\to \mathrm{hom}(M,B)\to\mathrm{hom}(M,C)$ is exact for every $M$, which is even a bit harder than your theorem! Of course, one probably did this verification earlier, when verifying that the background category is abelian, but one way or another the same amount of work has to be done.